# Open multiple Word docs

Tags: vba, excel

Just for starters, I have limited VBA experience, and I am mostly modifying stuff that I saw posted online.  I have an Excel macro that takes data out of a Table (or tables) in a Word Table.  My problem is that I have something like a thousand Word Documents, so I would like help with a solution that copies the data from all Word Documents in a user selected folder.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub ImportWordTables()

'Imports cells from Word document Tables in multiple documents

   Dim wdDoc         As Object
   Dim TableNo       As Integer  'number of tables in Word doc
   Dim iTable        As Integer  'table number index
   Dim iRow          As Long     'row index in Excel
   Dim iCol          As Integer  'column index in Excel
   Dim ix  As Long
   ix = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastRow = ix

   wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc*),*.doc*", MultiSelect = True, _
         "Browse for files containing table to be imported")


   If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

   Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName)   'open Word file

   With wdDoc
      TableNo = 1
      If TableNo = 0 Then
         MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
               vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"

      End If

      For iTable = 1 To TableNo
         With .tables(iTable)
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells in column A and B
            Cells(ix + 1, "A") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(1, 2))
            Cells(ix + 1, "B") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(2, 2))
            Cells(ix + 1, "C") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(3, 2))
            Cells(ix + 1, "D") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(4, 2))
            Cells(ix + 1, "E") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(5, 2))
            Cells(ix + 1, "F") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(6, 2))
            Cells(ix + 1, "G") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(6, 3))
            Cells(ix + 1, "H") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(7, 2))
            Cells(ix + 1, "I") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(8, 2))
            Cells(ix + 1, "J") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(9, 2))
            Cells(ix + 1, "K") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(10, 2))
Cells(ix + 1, "L") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(13, 2))
         End With
         Next iTable
   End With


   Set wdDoc = Nothing
       End Sub
```

I know that I need to create a loop, but I couldn't alter any of the loop examples I found in similar questions to work.

Answer (score 2):

Although I most likely wouldn't consider using Excel to collect data from Tables in "thousands" of Word documents I did find this an interesting exercise so here is some code that i put together to do what (I think) you are asking. I have included a few things here that you may want to investigate that, admittedly, go way beyond what you had asked for but I tried to comment the code so that you can figure out what I'm trying to accomplish.

Also . . . One really important note about Office Automation. Since Office applications are based on the COM specification (at least the earlier ones, not sure about the newer versions) you have to be REALLY careful in how you go about creating and destroying objects. COM enforces a rule that says if there is an object that is holding a reference to another object then that other object cannot be destroyed. This has serious implications in Office Automation because most of the objects hold references to each other in all sorts of directions. For instance in Excel; not only does the Excel application hold a reference to the Workbook and the Workbook holds a reference to the Worksheet. The Worksheet holds a reference to the Workbook (through it's Parent property) and the so on up the line. Therefore If you create an instance of Excel and then get a reference to a Workbook and then get a reference to a Worksheet within that Workbook, you can try to destroy that Workbook object all day long and it won't ever go away because the Worksheet is holding a reference to it. Same holds true for the Excel application object. When creating references to objects in Office it is always a best practice to destroy objects in the reverse order in which they were created. Create: Excel=>Workbook=>Worksheet. Destroy: Set Worksheet = Nothing => Workbook.Close, Set Workbook = Nothing => Excel.Quit, Set Excel = Nothing.

Not following this general rule has caused countless machines to crash because three or four instances of Excel (which chews up a lot of memory) are left open on a machine because the process has been run several times and the objects have not been destroyed.

Okay . . . I'll get off my soap box now. Here is the code I created. Enjoy!

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LoadWordData()
    On Error GoTo Err_LoadWordData

    Dim procName As String
    Dim oWks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oWordDoc As Word.Document '* Requires a reference to the Microsoft Word #.# Object Library
    Dim oTbl As Word.Table
    Dim oFSO As FileSystemObject '* Requires a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library
    Dim oFiles As Files
    Dim oFile As File
    Dim oAnchor As Excel.Range

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim fReadOnly As Boolean
    Dim iTableNum As Integer
    Dim iRowOffset As Long

    procName = "basGeneral::LoadWordData()"

    fReadOnly = True
    Set oWks = GetWordDataWks()

    If Not oWks Is Nothing Then
        iRowOffset = oWks.UsedRange.Row + oWks.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
        strPath = GetPath()

        If strPath <> "" Then
            Set oWord = New Word.Application
            Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject
            Set oAnchor = oWks.Range("$A$1")


            Set oFiles = oFSO.GetFolder(strPath).Files

            For Each oFile In oFiles
                If IsWordDoc(oFile.Type) Then
                    iTableNum = 0
                    Set oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(strPath & oFile.Name, , fReadOnly)

                    For Each oTbl In oWordDoc.Tables
                        iTableNum = iTableNum + 1

                        oAnchor.Offset(iRowOffset, 0).Formula = oFile.Name
                        oAnchor.Offset(iRowOffset, 1).Formula = iTableNum
                        oAnchor.Offset(iRowOffset, 2).Formula = GetCellValue(oTbl, 1)
                        oAnchor.Offset(iRowOffset, 3).Formula = GetCellValue(oTbl, 2)
                        oAnchor.Offset(iRowOffset, 4).Formula = GetCellValue(oTbl, 3)
                        oAnchor.Offset(iRowOffset, 5).Formula = GetCellValue(oTbl, 4)
                        oAnchor.Offset(iRowOffset, 6).Formula = GetCellValue(oTbl, 5)
                        oAnchor.Offset(iRowOffset, 7).Formula = GetCellValue(oTbl, 6)

                        iRowOffset = iRowOffset + 1
                    Next oTbl

                    oWordDoc.Close
                    Set oWordDoc = Nothing
                End If
            Next oFile
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "The Worksheet to store the data could not be found. All actions have been cancelled.", vbExclamation, "Word Table Data Worksheet Missing"
    End If

Exit_LoadWordData:
    On Error Resume Next
    '* Make sure you cleans things up in the proper order
    '* This is EXTREAMLY IMPORTANT! We close and destroy the
    '* document here again in case something errored and we
    '* left one hanging out there. This can leave multiple
    '* instances of Word open chewing up A LOT of memory.
    Set oTbl = Nothing
    oWordDoc.Close
    Set oWordDoc = Nothing
    oWord.Quit
    Set oWord = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set oFiles = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oAnchor = Nothing
    MsgBox "The processing has been completed.", vbInformation, "Processing Complete"
    Exit Sub

Err_LoadWordData:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error in Proc: " & procName
    Resume Exit_LoadWordData

End Sub

Private Function GetPath() As String
    On Error GoTo Err_GetPath

    Dim procName As String
    Dim retVal As String

    procName = "basGeneral::GetPath()"

    '* This is where you can use the FileDialogs to pick a folder
    '* I'll leave that up to you, I'll just pick the folder that
    '* my workbook is sitting in.
    '*
    retVal = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

Exit_GetPath:
    On Error Resume Next
    GetPath = retVal
    Exit Function

Err_GetPath:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error in Proc: " & procName
    Resume Exit_GetPath

End Function

Private Function IsWordDoc(ByVal pFileType As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Err_IsWordDoc

    Dim procName As String
    Dim retVal As Boolean
    Dim iStart As Integer

    procName = "basGeneral::IsWordDoc()"

    '* This could obviously have been done in may different ways
    '* including in a single statement.
    '* I did it this way so it would be obvious what is happening
    '*
    '* You could examine the file extension as well but you'd have
    '* to strip it off yourself because the FileSystemObject doesn't
    '* have that property
    '* Plus there are moree than one extension for Word documents
    '* these days so you'd have to account for all of them.
    '* This was, simply, the easiest and most thorough in my opinion
    '*
    retVal = False

    iStart = InStr(1, pFileType, "Microsoft")
    If iStart > 0 Then
        iStart = InStr(iStart, pFileType, "Word")
        If iStart > 0 Then
            iStart = InStr(iStart, pFileType, "Document")
            If iStart > 0 Then
                retVal = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

Exit_IsWordDoc:
    On Error Resume Next
    IsWordDoc = retVal
    Exit Function

Err_IsWordDoc:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error in Proc: " & procName
    Resume Exit_IsWordDoc

End Function

Private Function GetWordDataWks() As Excel.Worksheet
    On Error GoTo Err_GetWordDataWks

    Dim procName As String
    Dim retVal As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    procName = "basGeneral::GetWordDataWks()"

    Set retVal = Nothing

    '* Here's the deal . . . I really try hard not to EVER use the
    '* ActiveWorkbook and ActiveWorksheet objects because you can never
    '* be absolutely certain what you will get. I prefer to explicitly
    '* go after the objects I need like I did here.
    '*
    '* I also never try to get a reference to a Worksheet using it's Tab Name.
    '* Users can easily change the Tab Name and that can really mess up all
    '* your hard work. I always use the CodeName which you can find (and set)
    '* in the VBA IDE in the Properties window for the Worksheet.
    '*
    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wks.CodeName = "wksWordData" Then
            Set retVal = wks
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wks

Exit_GetWordDataWks:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWordDataWks = retVal
    Exit Function

Err_GetWordDataWks:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error in Proc: " & procName
    Resume Exit_GetWordDataWks

End Function

Private Function GetCellValue(ByRef pTable As Word.Table, ByVal pRow As Long) As Variant
    On Error GoTo Err_GetCellValue

    Dim procName As String
    Dim retVal As Variant
    Dim strValue As String

    procName = "basGeneral::GetCellValue()"

    strValue = WorksheetFunction.Clean(pTable.cell(pRow, 2).Range.Text)

    If IsNumeric(strValue) Then
        retVal = Val(strValue)
    Else
        retVal = strValue
    End If

Exit_GetCellValue:
    On Error Resume Next
    GetCellValue = retVal
    Exit Function

Err_GetCellValue:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error in Proc: " & procName
    Resume Exit_GetCellValue

End Function
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the help with the project. I completely understand what you mean about excel not being the best solution. That said, I'm getting a compile error regarding: Private Function GetCellValue(ByRef pTable As Word.Table, ByVal pRow As Long) As Variant saying that it's not defined. I'll try to figure it out, but if you're online, first of all, thank you, and second of all, do I just need to define it at the top?
Edit: the specific error is that a "user-defined type not defined"

Comment: Any chance you didn't catch the subtl comments I put in the code about setting references to the Word and Scripting libraries. It was in the main subroutine. You need to set references to the Microsoft Word #.# Object Library and the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library. That should take care of that error.

Comment: Yeah . . . that function uses the Word.Table object in it's parameter list. That requires the reference to the Word Object Library.

Comment: Okay, I stopped being dumb and loaded the references listed in the markup.  Sorry.

Comment: Crap. Next question. I'm getting the error I see you have set up here: The Worksheet to store the data could not be found. All actions have been cancelled. It seems that it should be using the current open workbook, but for whatever reason, it's not loading.

Comment: In the GetWordDataWks function you'll need to change the CodeName of the sheet it is looking for to whatever your Worksheet's CodeName is. Again . . . that can be found (and set) in the Properties window in the VBA IDE. Just click on the Worksheet in the Project Explorer

Comment: Thank you very much.  I swear I read the markup . . . I unfortunately didn't understand it.  Again, I sadly know much less VBA than I should.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark this as the answer and vote it up a notch. Good luck, Doug